# Dynamic request model in FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

I'm writing a class-based generic CRUD router/handler in FastAPI and need something similar to `response_model` for the request, to generate a Swagger UI to the input model without writing a separate function for the endpoint. Example for reading a user model and filtering it base on it's username:

```py
class ModelReadHandler:
  def __init__(self, base_url: str, response_model_cls: type, request_model_cls: type):
    self.router = APIRouter()
    self.response_model = response_model_cls
    self.request_model = request_model_cls
    self.add_routes()
  def add_routes():
    self.router.add_api_route(f'/{self.base_url}/', self.read, methods=['GET'],
                               response_model=self.response_model)
  def read(self, input_model: self.request_model_cls # ** actually can't do this but looking the behaviour of this hypothetical code 
           session: Depends(get_session),
           ):
    query = input_model.get_read_query()
    return session.exec(query).all()

# -- the input_model would extend this abstract class
class InputModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
  def get_read_query(self):
    raise NotImplementedError()

# class example for InputModel
class UserInputModel(InputModel):
  username: int
  def get_read_query(self):
    return select(UserModel).where(UserModel.username == self.username)

# and we instantiate the user handler like this
user_handler = ModelReadHandler(base_url='user',
                                request_model_cls=UserInputModel,
                                response_model_cls=UserModel)

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(user_handler.router)
```

Now this doesn't work because there is no way to set the type of the `input_model` argumnent in `ModelReadhandler.read()`. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour? - the goal is to add dynamically generated endpoints with swagger uis indicating their request parameters.

###### Note

An alternative is to extend the class for each model and type hint according to the model. I do not want that.

Answer (score -2):

FastAPI supports defining request models as Pydantic models and uses the defined models to automatically generate Swagger UI documentation for the request parameters. You can use the Body class from fastapi.params to define the request model for the endpoint.

```py
class ModelReadHandler:
  def __init__(self, base_url: str, response_model_cls: type, request_model_cls: type):
    self.router = APIRouter()
    self.response_model = response_model_cls
    self.request_model = request_model_cls
    self.add_routes()
  def add_routes():
    self.router.add_api_route(f'/{self.base_url}/', self.read, methods=['GET'],
                               response_model=self.response_model)
  def read(self, input_model: Body(self.request_model)
           session: Depends(get_session),
           ):
    query = input_model.get_read_query()
    return session.exec(query).all()
```

```py
# the input_model would extend this abstract class
class InputModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
  def get_read_query(self):
    raise NotImplementedError()

# class example for InputModel
class UserInputModel(InputModel):
  username: int
  def get_read_query(self):
    return select(UserModel).where(UserModel.username == self.username)
```

```py
# and we instantiate the user handler like this
user_handler = ModelReadHandler(base_url='user',
                                request_model_cls=UserInputModel,
                                response_model_cls=UserModel)

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(user_handler.router)
```

Comment: The line `input_model: Body(self.request_model)` in the arg list would not work because `self` is not bound yet.